# Spring Oauth 2 authorization code grant for clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, docusignapi, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to build a web application where the user can log in with their credentials stored in my DB.
After logging in, I need to get an access token from third party REST API and store in the session. The Third-party REST API uses Oauth2 with authorization code grant. I have seen many articles on implementing oauth2 for login in spring but not accessing third party API after logging in.

The third-party app is Docusign.

The following is my application.properties file

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.client-name=demo-auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.client-id=XXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.client-secret=XXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.scope=signature
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/home
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.docusign.provider=docusign

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.docusign.token-uri=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.docusign.authorization-uri=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.docusign.user-info-uri=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo
```

I am stuck on how to get my access token after this. I am getting any on how to get my access token after writing this file.
And I also don't know how to check if this OAuth registration is successful or not. Please, someone, help me

***Pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>docusign-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>docusign-demo</name>
    <description>Docusign POC</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
            <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Maybe to make it easier, start with this - https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator and make sure you can get that working. You will need to change to real OAuth flow quickly later, but just to get you unstuck right now

Comment: Currently, I am using the OAuth token. My application is working with this token. I want to change it to authorization code grant so that I don't need to replace the tokens every time it expires. The code examples don't give any idea on how the tokens are generated and used.

Comment: got it, here is another idea, can you try this code - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant and see if you can get it working? it's just a matter of updating your IK and clientSecret